# Equation Involving Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

I'm tasked with proving the following equivalency:

Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci number at n, or $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}, n >=2$

Show that:

$$\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+2}}=\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}}$$

I tried filling in the definition $F_n$ which yielded the following:

$$\frac{1}{(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})(F_{n+1}+F_n)}=\frac{1}{(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})(F_{n}+F_{n-1})}-\frac{1}{(F_{n}+F_{n-1})(F_{n+1}+F_{n})}$$

Which looked promising, with binomial terms that might potentially cancel each other out or reduce cleanly. But after almost an hour of algebraic gymnastics I just can't get both sides to look exactly like the other.

EDIT: Getting a common denominator is key, I'm just struggling to find the exact form that causes everything to reduce in such a way that it proves the equivalence.

Comment: Try multiplying both sides  by $F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}$.

Comment: Get a common denominator for the two fractions on the right hand side.

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried that, but couldn't get everything to cancel out that needed to. I have to assume the answer lies down that path though so I'll keep at it. I think I may have over-complicated things when I tried plugging in the expanded definition of the $F_n$

Comment: What is the most obvious common denominator for $\dfrac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}$ and $\dfrac{1}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer response in the OP.

Comment: How can you say that $F_{n+2}-F_n=1$? Did you try any example?

Comment: You let a factor of $F_{n+1}$ vanish in the denominator.

Comment: @DanielFischer yeah I just caught that. Ok I think I have it now, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{F_n F_{n+2}} + \frac{1}{F_{n+1} F_{n+2}} &= \frac{F_{n+1}F_{n+2} + F_{n}F_{n+2}}{F_{n}F_{n+1}F_{n+2}^2} \\
&= \frac{F_{n+1} + F_{n}}{F_{n}F_{n+1}F_{n+2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+1}}\end{align*}
Thus $$\frac{1}{F_n F_{n+2}} = \frac{1}{F_{n}F_{n+1}}\ - \frac{1}{F_{n+1} F_{n+2}}$$

Comment: It should be the Difference of the two expressions, not the Sum, but I know the answer is something very similar to this

Comment: I just added the second term on the right to both sides...

Comment: I guess I should say, use my answer them subtract the second term on the left side from both sides...

Comment: Oh! Right, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
F_{n+2} &=F_{n+1}+F_{n}\\[2ex]
F_{n+1} &=F_{n+2}-F_{n}\\[2ex]
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}} &= \frac{F_{n+2}}{F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}}-\frac{F_{n}}{F_nF_{n+1}F_{n+2}}\\[2ex]
\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+2}} &=\frac{1}{F_nF_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{F_{n+1}F_{n+2}}
\end{align}$$